# which electric device can scan all waves exist at home

Tags: appliances

which electric device can scan all waves exist at home.

would like to find which channel of waves home appliance using and find hidden waves or communication channel or wireless or microwaves or other kind of waves emitted from home appliance

do amazon sell this scanner? what is the name of it?
if really can scanned this, how to visualize and observe what is in the channel or waves?

Comment: Voting to close this as virtual duplicate of another posting by same member.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question speculates on a device that does not exist for an unknown purpose. This has nothing do do with home improvement.

Comment: A **spectrum analyzer** is what you're looking for, you'll have to do further research as to the frequency pass band coverage you want.

Answer (score 0):

> **which electric device can scan all waves exist at home.**

None.

Devices specialise. You won't find one that scans seismic waves at the same time as ultraviolet electromagnetic waves, radar electromagnetic waves and ultrasonic waves.

Comment: Let's also include light waves and sound waves.